# Firebase App Check: Throttled when running it with Test Lab devices

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-app-check

Running our app on multiple devices using Firebase Test Lab and upon seeing its log, the Firebase App Check is getting throttled. What could be the possible solution to this?

```
09-21 22:51:55.551: W/LocalRequestInterceptor(7303): Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead. Error: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: -8: Integrity API error (-8): The calling app is making too many requests to the API and hence is throttled.
09-21 22:51:55.926: W/KeyStore(3468): KeyStore exception
09-21 22:51:55.926: W/KeyStore(3468): android.os.ServiceSpecificException: (code 7)
09-21 22:51:55.926: W/KeyStore(3468): at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1956)
09-21 22:51:55.926: W/KeyStore(3468): at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1910)
09-21 22:51:55.926: W/KeyStore(3468): at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1860)
09-21 22:51:56.706: W/Finsky(2931): [150] ikc.i(10): IOException while manually unzipping request.
09-21 22:51:56.707: E/Finsky(2931): com.google.android.finsky.integrityservice.IntegrityException
09-21 22:51:57.587: W/KeyStore(3468): KeyStore exception
09-21 22:51:57.587: W/KeyStore(3468): android.os.ServiceSpecificException: (code 7)
09-21 22:51:57.587: W/KeyStore(3468): at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1956)
09-21 22:51:57.587: W/KeyStore(3468): at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1910)
09-21 22:51:57.587: W/KeyStore(3468): at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1860)
09-21 22:51:58.627: W/Finsky(2931): [147] ikc.i(10): IOException while manually unzipping request.
09-21 22:51:58.661: E/Finsky(2931): com.google.android.finsky.integrityservice.IntegrityException
09-21 22:51:58.672: W/LocalRequestInterceptor(7303): Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead. Error: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: -8: Integrity API error (-8): The calling app is making too many requests to the API and hence is throttled.
09-21 22:51:58.836: W/GCM-GMS(4915): Failed to get registration: java.io.IOException: QUOTA_EXCEEDED
```